# Should I manually copy my Recovery partition after migrating OS?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, migration

I have migrated my OS to a new hard drive. My old hard drive has 3 partitions:

1. The Main partition
2. "System Reserved" partition
3. "Recovery" partition

However, the one named "Recovery" did not get copied over during the migration process, and I'm not sure whether Win10 actually needs that partition or if it's a remnant from a previous Win7 installation, but that's the partition that actually contains *Winre.wim* on it

Here's the content of both partitions:
[image: Recovery]
[image: System Reserved]
[image: System Reserve\Boot]

So, I'm wondering whether I should manually clone the "Recovery" partition or if it's safe to ignore it.

Comment: “and I'm not sure whether Win10 actually needs that partition“ - it’s not required but if at any point Windows needs to boot into the WinRE and allow you to run commands to repair the installation you will need to boot to an WinRE environment yourself instead of it happening automatically

Comment: So a Windows 10 USB will do the job?

Comment: Will it allow you to boot into recovery environment, yes it will.  Easier to create the recovery partition though.  I would migrate all of your partitions, personally

Comment: @Ranhound, so I should clone the partition myself? I'm not sure why EaseUS didn't copy the partition.